# Is it best to separate the dashboard to a new subdomain when your landing page is static generated using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We already have multiple pages that are statically generated by Next.js using the command

```
next build && next export
```

and hosted on AWS S3

My question is if we need to build a dashboard with firebase authentication and a stripe subscription, should we create a new app and host it to a subdomain? probably using a create-react-app instead of next.js?

Comment: There's no need for you to do that, you can have a CSR page (dashboard page) co-exist with statically exported pages. In terms of what's best, that's really up to you/your requirements.

Comment: Most of the websites using subdomains use em because they have different teams working on them or really needed to use one. If you're building the app alone or with a small team keeping it organised in a same domain is more suitable for user experience as they do not need to remember extra sub domain to get to their dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

have look at this little survey. most of the developers advised to have everything on the main domain.

https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/qdcdvv/use_nextjs_for_landing_page_and_app_as_mono_repo/

i have talked to several successful startups and they stated that if they could redo it they would prefer to have it on a single domain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).